# Property 'id' does not exist on type '{} | BoardType'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am working with Typescript in my Reactjs ( v18 ) version. I have a problem below

```
export interface BoardType {
  id: string,
  columnOrder: string[] | [],
  columns: string[]
}

const [board, setBoard] = useState<BoardType | {}>({});

const ABC = board.id; // Property 'id' does not exist on type '{} | BoardType'
```

I don't know why this error happened. Could someone explain it to me? Thanks for your support!

Comment: board is an empty object. It does not have the key `id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are giving the initial state : `{}` in `useState`

`BoardType` has an id but `{}` does not. So `board` which is `BoardType | {}` may not have one.

You can use optional chaining and you will get undefined if `board` is `{}`

Like this : `const ABC = board?.id;`

Comment: Thank you so much, I resolved my problem by set type is BoardType, because it  will be better

Answer (score 1):

makes no sense to setBoard to an empty object. Make it null...

```js
    const [board, setBoard] = useState<BoardType | null>();
    const ABC = board?.id;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I resolved my problem by set the type is BoardType, because it will be better